# Eclipse: how to remove a directory tree from a CVS repository?

Tags: eclipse, directory, cvs, delete-file

The project I am developing with Eclipse is under CVS version control and I have successfully used the "Team -> Add to Version Control" function to add an entire directory tree into the repository. However, there seems to be no way in Eclipse to remove files from the repository... is that true? The "Team" tab does not include any remove function and simply deleting files does not remove them from CVS.

I know how to remove files and folders from a CVS repository using `cvs remove` on the command-line, but it would be just so convenient to have Eclipse do all the recursive deleting for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse just use the regular **Delete** functionality; when you synchronize or commit to your repo, the file(s) you've deleted will be removed. Like most cvs actions, it's a multi-step process: you make the change locally and then commit it to the repo. With remove (and add), there are actually 3 steps:

1. Delete local copy from your local file system.
2. Issue `cvs remove` command.
3. [Sometime later] Commit changes to the repo (including the remove you did in step 2).

Eclipse just consolidates #2 and #3 for you via the commit or synchronize functions.

See http://docs.freebsd.org/info/cvs/cvs.info.Removing_files.html

Comment: So when deleting the file, there is no interaction with CVS yet, but the `cvs remove` is postponed until synchronizing or committing the repo?

Comment: Still I don't understand why there is a "Team > Add" function in Eclipse that performs steps 1 and 2 (including the `cvs add`), but there is no "Team > Remove" that does the equivalent for removing files. But I guess you anyway answered my question ;)

Comment: *Team* > *Add* does not actually create a file for you; the file must already exist locally. What Eclipse can do for you is combining steps 2 and 3 (for both add and remove), if you use *Team* > *Synchronize*.